# Server bandwidth usage monitoring

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, bandwidth

I'm using ubuntu 11.04.

What I would like to be able to do, is to be able to view in a browser front end, the amount of in/out network data of the PROCESSES running on my machine.

Anyone know if and how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) can show you what you want, but from a shell. A GUI can be built on top of it if you're willing to do the work (ala [BusyTasks](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=143833)).

Comment: Awesome minus the lack of WebGui.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ganglia.

http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/

Also, cacti.

http://www.cacti.net/